# What does "get a pass" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> A: how come Dianne Feinstein **gets a pass** having a Chinese spy on her payroll?
>
> B: She **gets a pass** cuz she was ignorant as hell.

I saw this exchange from a comment of [this article](https://www.yahoo.com/finance/video/chinas-economy-nowhere-near-cratering-122300444.html). What does "get a pass" truly mean in this context?  I looked it up and it seem not to be a set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that she can be *excused* from the restrictions that are placed on others—that an exception is made in her case.

The meaning likely comes from the high school related term [**hall pass**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hall%20pass):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> *US*
>   : a card that shows that a student has permission to be out of class during class time

The term was generally shortened to just *pass*.

I don't believe it's commonly used in a high school context anymore, but it's still worked its way into regular use such as in your example.